# Combining textures in a 3D scan

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, scanning

I am using a new 3D scanner which uses stereophotogrammetry to extract images at different orientations and then stitch them together to create a 3D model. The model looks great. However, the texture in the models (as referred to in the .mtl file) points to several images(.jpg) corresponding to the orientation. (Every capture has its own texture and they are referenced in the .mtl file). However, my application can only read 3D scans (.obj's) with only one texture referenced in them. Can you advise a way to combine the textures to a single triangle map or UV map?
The textures and the final models are added for your reference.
Please advise if you need any more information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of your model and/or the textures?

Comment: @ScottMilner: Please find the images attached.

Comment: You say your app only supports one material .objs - add support for more. Blender can import objs with more than one material, you could bake the materials into one, or use projection painting to paint a material onto another and then re-export them. You might also look at substance painter.

Comment: So your model file knows which texture to use for each poly...that's a good start. Unfortunately, the problem is not easy.

You first need to create a UV map for the mesh itself. Doing so will give you a map from your polygonal faces to UV coordinates that span a _single_ 'texture space.'

Once you have such a map, you need to copy your independent textures, on a per-poly basis, to a new, combined texture. You need to use your model file to see which texture is mapped to a given poly, then copy the appropriate part of that texture into your new, combined texture _using the UV map_

Comment: As @sambler says, it would probably be easiest to add multi-material support to your application _or_ to use a different application to perform the UV unwrapping / baking process that I described above.

Comment: @sambler: Can you explain more? I don't think that I understand. I am very new to blender. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshParnell: Thanks for your comments. But can you please explain further. I am new to Blender.

Comment: I'm sorry @Praveen, unfortunately I do not know Blender either :/

Comment: @JoshParnell Thanks Josh. Okay, can you advice any other platform other than Blender to perform those manipulations that you described?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143916/discussion-between-praveen-and-josh-parnell).

Comment: While [baking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/bake.html) is often used to make normal or AO maps you can also use it to bake multiple or procedural textures onto one image. [Projection painting](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+projection+painting) allows you to use one material as the paint brush that another image receives, by painting each source texture onto the same target you combine them together.

Comment: @sambler: Thank you for the insights. That's really interesting. But I would like to retain the original texture of the scan rather than painting a texture all over. Do you think your process would help us achieve whats desired?

Comment: You choose what image receives the painting, you only need to use the existing ones as the source for the brush.

Comment: @sambler: Can you explain the procedure?

Comment: The previous link is of several video tutorials that explain it.